How can you dynamically create a link to a Slack user profile if all you know is the organization and username?
I want to dynamically create a link to a Slack user profile or DM, but literally all I know is the organization and username (not the user ID). I cannot use the Slack API, and I cannot rely on any manual process. For example...
Given an organization of "my_org" and a username of "my_username", my canonical profile URL would be something like this: https://my_org.slack.com/archives/ABCD12345. But unless that ID is some kind of hash, I have no way to get it.
Linking to a channel with the same constraints is easy. I can just plug in the channel name as-is, like this: https://my_org.slack.com/app_redirect?channel=my_channel. That's what I want to do with the user profile or DM.
To illustrate using PHP code, I would like to do this:
// This is EVERYTHING I know:
$org = 'my_org';
$username = 'my_username';

// This is what I want to do:
$profile = 'https://{$org}.slack.com/what_goes_here?{$username}';

I have searched the Slack documentation, and it seems like the feature would be one one of these pages, if anywhere: Reference: Deep linking into Slack
 or Create a link to a member's profile
. But they don't give any hint of such a feature's existence. I have a suspicion it just can't be done, but maybe someone will prove me wrong.

Slack support gave me the answer: the format is https://my_org.slack.com/team/my_username. Or, as PHP:
$org = 'my_org';
$username = 'my_username';
$profile = 'https://{$org}.slack.com/team/{$username}';

